# How can I link two tables to get data from both - php/phpmyadmin

Tags: php, mysql, database, join, phpmyadmin

Hi there sorry I'm not sure how to explain this but I'm creating a website that allows students to loan books out.

I have 2 tables:

**Table 1 - BOOKLOAN**
BookID
StudentID
DateOut
DateIn

**Table 2 - BOOK**
BookID
BookTitle
BookAuthor
BookCategory
BookPrice

The website saves all the books that get loaned out to students in the BOOKLOAN table. Students can take out multiple books. How can I get details of a specific students list of books they've taken out? I need all the details from the BOOK table but only the ones where it's listed in the BOOKLOAN table that the student has taken it out?

Does anyone have any idea how I go about this? I have tried doing them as separate queries and as a single one but neither work it just comes up with errors.

Comment: Pleaese read & act on hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & show what you have tried. See [mcve]. Also [ask] & the downvote arrow mouseover text.

Comment: And read up on relational database design.

Answer (score 0):

you can try whit 
Select t0.*,t1.StudentID, t1.DateOut, t1.DateIn
From Book t0
Inner Join Bookloan t1 On t0.BookID = t1.BookID